# How can I call a method from the MainClass in to a fragment?

Tags: android, mobile, android-fragments, methods

I've got two methods in the **MainClass** that look like this...

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}


public void setUI() {

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setTitle("No internet connection");
    builder.setMessage("message ")
            .setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    // if connection is back, dialod dissapears, else pops out again
                    if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
                        builder.show();
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            });
    //  .setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    // public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    //  User cancelled the dialog --> soft-close the app?
    //   finish();

    //} });
    if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
        builder.show();
    }     is this possible to call this 2 methods in a fragment?Thank you in advance.
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: What do you mean by MainClass? Is it an Activity where you have added the fragment?

Comment: My question is How can I call a method from the MainClass in to a fragment?>>>>Is it an Activity where you have added the fragment?<<<<<Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your mainClass extends `FragmentActiviy` and you have these two methods.
create MainClass instance in fragment like

```
mainclass=(MainClass)getActivity();
```

and call methods like

```
mainclass.isNetworkAvailable();
mainclss.setUI();
```